# Salt Stack - Best way to get schedule output

Tags: schedule, salt-stack

I'm using saltstack on my servers. I did a simple schedule:

```
job1:
  schedule.present:
    - function: state.apply
    - seconds: 1800
    - splay: 5
```

Now I want to get the output of the schedule back on my master 
(or on my minion but I just like to know the best way)

I don't really know how to use salt mine or returners or what is best preferred for my needs.

thank you :)

Comment: I guess you already read [the docs](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/jobs/). Which way to pick depends on your use case. If you decide to tell us about your needs we might give you advice :)

Answer (score 3):

## Job data return and job metadata

By default, data about jobs runs from the Salt scheduler is returned to the master.

It can therefore be useful to include specific data to differentiate a job from other jobs. By using the `metadata` parameter a value can be associated with a scheduled job, although these `metadata` values aren't used in the execution of the job they can be used to search for specific job later.

```
job1:
  schedule.present:
    - function: state.apply
    - seconds: 1800
    - splay: 5
    - metadata:
        foo: bar
```

An example job search on the salt-master might look similar to this:

```
salt-run jobs.list_jobs search_metadata='{"foo": "bar"}'
```

Take a look at the [salt.runners.jobs](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/runners/all/salt.runners.jobs.html#salt.runners.jobs.list_jobs) documentation for more examples.

## Scheduler with returner

The `schedule.present` function includes a parameter to set a returner to use to return the results of the scheduled job. You could for example use the `pushover` returner:

```
job1:
  schedule.present:
    - function: state.apply
    - seconds: 1800
    - splay: 5
    - returner: pushover
```

Take a look at the [returners](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/returners/index.html) documentation for a full list of of builtin returners and usage information.